# search 2 different columns in 2 different dataset in R

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements

I have 2 data frames :

`df1`, with only strings

```
Act1
ESP
BCN
FTP
```

And a second data frame `df2` with string and numeric values

```
Act val
ESP   1
FR    2
FTP   3
BCN   4
```

I want to replace values in column `Act1` by the associated number in column val, if `df1$Act == df2$Act` doing a for loop or something similar to compare values for the 2 different data set and columns

get a third data frame `df3` with

```
Act1
1
4
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
df1$Act1 <- df2$val[match(df1$Act1, df2$Act)]
df1
#   Act1
#1    1
#2    4
#3    3
```